# Как на товаре woocommerce сделать кнопку, которая бы вела на страницу со списком категорий к которым относится товар?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

кнопку уже сделал!
Не могу понять как сделать чтоб при ее нажатии перекидывало на список(страницу) c категориями к которым относится этот товар
вот код кнопки

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');


add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$cat = get_the_category($product->ID);
echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat->cat_ID).'" class="button 
addtocartbutton">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например как вариант можно сделать вот так:

Необходимо создать новую страницу, назвать ее например: **Страница с категориями продукта**,а так же указать ссылку "**/category-product/**" как в примере(или изменить на свою).

Далее создать новый файл "product_cat.php" в корне темы "\wp-content\themes\название_темы" и вставить туда код приведенный ниже.

Далее, на новой только что созданной странице выберите Шаблон "**Страница с категориями товара**"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подкорректируйте свой код в function.php как указанно ниже.

Вот и все. При нажатии на кнопку под товаром, будет открываться страница с категориями которые принадлежат данному товару.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Файл Function.php

```
function remove_loop_button(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 
        'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');


add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
 global $post, $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    $site_url = get_site_url();

    echo '<a href="'.$site_url.'/category-product/?product_id='.$id.'"  class="button 
    addtocartbutton">Страница с категориями продукта</a>';
}
```

> Файл product_cat.php:

```
<?php /*Template name: Страница с категориями товара */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="page_product_cat">   
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <?php    
     if (isset($_GET['product_id']) &&  $_GET['product_id']!=''  ) {
        $id = $_GET['product_id'];

         $terms = get_the_terms( $id, 'product_cat' );

         if ($terms) { 
            echo "ID продукта: <strong>". $id."</strong><br/><br/>"; 
            echo "Категории продукта: <br/>";
            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url( $term_link ).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';echo "</br>";
            } 
         }else{
            echo "Произошла ошибка, скорее всего такого продукта нет!";
         }

     }else{
        echo "ID Продукта не указан!";
     }

     ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


<style>
.page_product_cat {
    padding: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, выручели))

Comment: @user258149 Рад что помог, возникнут вопросы, задавайте.